# Listing files using a variable filter

Tags: linux, bash, variables, filter

I'm trying to list files using filters in a shell bash.

This example works:

```
result=$(ls *{A1,A2}*.txt)

echo $result
```

> file1_A1.txt,file2_A2.txt

But when puuting the filters into a variable, it doesn't work:

```
filter={A1,A2}
result=$(ls *"$filter"*.txt)
echo $result
```

> ls: cannot access '*{A1,A2}*': No such file or directory

I'm using a wrong sintax. How can I fix it?

Best

Comment: can you trying without escaping $filter with quotes? Because otherwise it won't expand

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Globs does not expand in a variable assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `eval` to achieve what you want (although I'm not a big fan of it; `eval` should be avoided whenever possible IMO):

```
filter="{A1,A2}"
result=$(eval "ls *$filter*.txt")
echo "$result"
```

There is probably no other way if you insist on using braces as *brace expansion* is done before any other expansion (e.g. variable expansion). See `man bash`, sections `EXPANSION` and `Brace Expansion`.

However, a possible workaround is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69599249/1976617).

Comment: Eval solved... tks! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Using extended globbing :

```
shopt -s extglob

filter="A1|A2"
result=(*@($filter)*.txt)
echo "${result[@]}"
```