# Shell script with ls -ls and OR patterns wildcards

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, ls

When entering

```
ls -ls /some/path/*{pattern1,pattern2}*.pdf
```

directly into the command prompt everything works, but when executing a file with the following content:

```
MAUI_PATH=/some/path/
WILDCARD=*{pattern1,pattern2}*.pdf

ls -ls ${LOCAL_PATH}${WILDCARD}
```

an error occurs: `ls: /some/path/*{pattern1,pattern2}*.pdf: No such file or directory`.

What am I doing wrong inside my script?

Comment: `{pattern1,pattern2}` cannot be saved in a shell variable.

Comment: See this question for both explanation on possible workarounds: [Listing files using a variable filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69599072/listing-files-using-a-variable-filter/69599155)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing files using a variable filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69599072/listing-files-using-a-variable-filter)